# Slide in window on button press[Titanium]

Tags: animation, window, titanium, slide

I have created a button to open a window. However, the window should slide in from the left side of the screen up to a certain distance.

For example, if I press the button, a window slide in till half of the screen. How can I achieve this effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for slider menu in titanium.here is its link

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-create-a-sliding-menu-for-ios/

Let me know if it help you

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
button.addEventListener( 'click', function(){

    var winInfo = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundImage: 'imagens/bg.png',
        url: 'informacoes.js',
    })

    var slide_it_left = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
    slide_it_left.left = 150

    winInfo.left = 320
    winInfo.open(slide_it_left)

})
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

A better solution of @Wahhab_mirza is to use an module created by viezel...

[NappSlideMenu](https://github.com/viezel/NappSlideMenu)

works for `js` and `alloy`